# Python version also shows a `+` symbol

Tags: python, python-2.7, compilation

I've been installing (compiling from source and then `make install`) python 2.7.12 since past few months on a few machines. After installation, I push the result of `python -V` and `pip -V` to a log file.

This has been going peachy on all of the AWS instances. I did this on my own machine, and running `python -V` gave me the following output:

> Python 2.7.12+

What does the `+` symbol mean? I couldn't find any documentation for the same anywhere.

Comment: @MioBambino Damn! Didn't find this when I was googling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-does-the-python-version-numbering-scheme-work.htm :

> You may also find version numbers with a “+” suffix, e.g. “2.2+”. These are unreleased versions, built directly from the subversion trunk. In practice, after a final minor release is made, the subversion trunk is incremented to the next minor version, which becomes the “a0” version, e.g. “2.4a0”.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a revision *past* the official 2.7.12 tag; it'll eventually  become 2.7.13, but only once a release candidate has been tagged.

The value is set in the [`Include/patchlevel.h` include file](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/7a8c8538bdb8/Include/patchlevel.h):

```c
#define PY_VERSION          "2.7.12+"
```

You have likely checked out the `2.7` *branch*; you could check out the `v2.7.12` tag instead, at which point you'll have the exact same software as what you installed on AWS.